# Which link field accepts an URL or a Node reference?

Tags: entities

I am looking for a field just like Link, but that allows the user enter a URL or via an autocomplete a node/entity reference.

This is because this field might be an external link or an internal link in which case it should refer to the entity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use 2 fields for that, the data types for an entity reference field and a text field aren't the same. Id be surprised if you find a pre built module to do that, entity references aren't supposed to store urls

Comment: You could just set the 'autocomplete_path' on the textfield (form_alter) to point to a custom function that returned the drupal menu paths. Not a bad idea for a module. EDIT: answer added with modules I found with this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of these modules can help.
[Advanced Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_link)
[Linkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit)

Answer (score 3):

In **Drupal 8** this works with normal link fields. You simply can choose if only internal, only external or both type of links can be entered in this field. You'll then get a autocomplete field that accepts either an entity title or an external link and a title.

Comment: You have to be aware that it's not a true entity reference. There's a little magic that core does to make it work. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.2.x/core/modules/link/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/LinkWidget.php#L75-77